# Maintance exam for Dev 401

Tags: certification, release-exam

I have completed my Salesforce dev401 exam in March28-2015. I suppose to complete my maintenance exam before March28-2016.
But i dint started any release online exams (Spring, Summer, Winter) yet.
Do i need to complete all these three release online exams before my maintenance exam?
If yes, i can see the release exams dates as below:
[image]
from the above, the Spring'16 is coming only after March 31st , but i suppose to complete my maintenance exam before march 28. 
So if I complete only two release online exams (summar, winter) is enough, and then shall I take my maintenance exam?
i am not sure what should i do next? 
Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get confused with the names. Both maintenance exam and release exam are literally same.

But in respect of maintaining your credential you have to maintain next year same release exam. So if you are certified for Winter 15, you need to complete Winter 16 release exam to maintain your credential.

So can I write Winter 16 release exam directly and maintain my credential?

No. You cannot write a release exam for Winter 16 without writing release exam of Summer 15. To complete Summer 15 you need to finish Spring 15. There is no need to finish Winter 15 release exam since your main exam is completed by Winter 15.

As far as date is concerned, your date of obtaining credential doesn't matter. What matters is the release.

For example, if Winter 15 main exam is available from March 1 2015 to June 30 2015, anyone who takes main exam between these two dates is certified for Winter 15. So they need to write Winter 16 release exam to maintain their credential. Each release exam will be available for almost 8 months.

I will ask you to complete Spring 15 and Summer 15 release exams first and pay for Winter 16 release exam and maintain your credential.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarifications@vigneshwaran ! I've just checked WebAssessor and seen that I can register for the Salesforce Certified Force.com Developer - Summar '15 and Winter '16 Release Exam i dont see Spring '15 in that list :(

Comment: If that's the case then I think your main exam is completed by Spring 15. The examples are for illustrative purpose only.

Comment: Understood ... Thanks for your clarifications @Vingneshwaran G